# Solr Join Query returning all documents

Tags: join, solr

I have documents added to SOLR in the following manner:

```
<doc>
    <str name="id">INDIA_18</str>
    <str name="textNew">text</str>
    <str name="description">d1</str>
    <str name="contentType">OLD</str>
</doc>
<doc>
    <str name="id">INDIA_17</str>
    <str name="textNew">text</str>
    <str name="description">d2</str>
    <str name="contentType">OLD</str>
</doc>
<doc>
    <str name="id">INDIA_16</str>
    <str name="textNew">text</str>
    <str name="description">d2</str>
    <str name="contentType">NEW</str>
</doc>
<doc>
    <str name="id">INDIA_15</str>
    <str name="textNew">text</str>
    <str name="description">d3</str>
    <str name="contentType">NEW</str>
</doc>
```

All the fields are STRING fields and id is the unique property of the document. I am using SOLR 4.0

I am running the following JOIN query of solr: **/select?q={!join+from=description+to=description}contentType:OLD**

As my understanding of the JOIN query, the above query would first SELECT description where contentType is OLD (result : d1, d2).
Then it will look for all the documents with contentType as d1, d2 and should thus return three documents as overall results. (2 with contentType as OLD and one with contentType as NEW)

But, on the contrary, the query returns all the four documents.

Can any body please look into the query/schema and point out what is the mistake.

Thanks in advance,
Sidharth.

Comment: does it work to put the join query in fq?  /select?q=*:*&fq={!join+from=description+to=description}contentType:OLD

Comment: Putting Join Query in fq still gives me all the results.